# Visualizing a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds

For the function $F: \mathbb{C}^3\to \mathbb{C}$, $(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+y^2+z^2$, $0$ is a regular value. So in particular, $F^{-1}(0)\subset \mathbb{C}^3$ is an embedded submanifold (of dimension 2 over $\mathbb{C}$ or dimension 4 over $\mathbb{R}$). I am having trouble however visioning what set looks like. My end goal is to put a CW structure on $q(\text{im}(F))$ where $q: \mathbb{C}^3\to \mathbb{C} P^2$ is the quotient map but I would like to understand what this submanifold looks like first. I have tried writing this out in terms of the real and complex parts of the three complex numbers. This gives relations 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 Re(z_i)=\sum_{i=1}^3 Im(z_i), \; \text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^3 Im(z_i)Re(z_i)=0.
$$
But I do not see how this would help. Its also clear that if $F(x,y,z)=0$, then $F(kx,ky,kz)=0$ for any $k\in \mathbb{C}$ but I don't know how to utilize this either.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some input on how to visualize this set or how I would go about putting a CW-structure on $q(\text{im}(F))$.

Comment: $0$ is not a regular value. The level set is a cone over a smooth conic, the image in $\Bbb P^2$, with vertex at the origin. You really need to work in projective space. The smooth conic is biholomorphic to $\Bbb P^1$. By the way, you should find Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions useful.

Comment: I see...Thank you for your comment. How would you go about showing that it is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Project from the point $[0,1,i]$ to the projective line $z=0$.